# Minimizing a functional with a free boundary condition

Tags: functional-equations, calculus-of-variations, boundary-value-problem, euler-lagrange-equation, functional-calculus

> Find the extremals of the functional
> $$\text{J}(y)=  y^2(1)  + \int_0^1 y'^2(x)dx   , \qquad y(0)=1.$$
> Answer: $y(x)=1-\frac{1}{2}x$.

My solution:

$$ F (x,y,y')=y'^2(x).$$

After solving the Euler Lagrange equation we get $$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}(2y')=0.$$

Which implies that $$y=\frac{a}{2}x+b,$$ using initial value condition we get $b=1$. Could you please help me find value of $a$?

Comment: Do you need to also deal with that $y^2(1)$?

Comment: Could you please give me some hint?

Comment: Calculate the functional for $y=ax/2+1$. Minimize the result in $a$.

Comment: What is the use of $y^2(1)$?

Comment: It is involved while calculating $J(ax/2+1)$. Try that calculation, and you'll see.

Comment: It is coming out to be $J(ax/2+1)=\frac{3a}{2}+1$

Comment: My doubt is that $y(1)$ is not given so how can I find a?

Comment: @zafran.  I get $J(  ax/2 + 1) =  \frac{1}{2}a^2 + a + 1.$    It seems there is an optimal value of $a.$

Comment: Yeah I made a mistake so sorry for that.

Comment: I got it thank you very much.

Comment: I suggest, for the sake of completeness, write an answer yourself that you accept.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that we can  write $J$ as

$$J(y) = \int_0^1 \left(2 y(x)y'(x) + y'(x)^2\right) \ dx \, + \, y(0)^2$$

Setting aside the constant $y(0)^2 = 1$ for now, we have $J$ as the integral of a function $F(y,y',x)$ where $F(y,y',x) = 2yy' + y'^2$.

You can now deploy your box of tricks on $F$ to find $y$. That is, the Euler-Lagrange equation:

$$0 = \frac{d \ }{dx} \frac{\partial F}{\partial y'} - \frac{\partial F}{\partial y} = \ ... $$

Comment: No comments, OPer? BTW, when you arrive at an answer, it should be very intuitive. Look at your original expression for $J$. What would one guess with all those positive, squared quantities?

Comment: What is the trick to convert the function?

Comment: You mean how did I decide how to rewrite $J(y)$ in that form? I wanted to use calculus of variations and to do that I had to find a way to get rid of the $y(1)^2$ term of the original, since it is not at all obvious how to deal with it directly. Turns out we could get rid of the $y(1)^2$ term by using $y(0)$, which has been given to us.

Comment: @SimonS proceeding, I hit $y(x)=Ax+1$, now how will I determine constant $A$? The only unused clue so far is "$y\in C^2([0,1])$".

Comment: @JessePFrancis Formally, substitute that expression back into either expression for $J$ and then evaluate the derivative $d/dA$ of that expression to find the value of $A$ that minimizes or maximizes the expression. Once you've got the answer, check that it makes intuitive sense. (Alternatively, look carefully at the expression and decide what the answer should be before you formally confirm it.)

Comment: @SimonS, thank you! Answer in duplicate question goes that way. So there's not much of significance for $y\in C^2([0,1])$?

Comment: @JessePFrancis If $y$ were not $C^2$ we would have trouble applying the E-L equation

Comment: @SImonS ..which is not mentioned in the other question! Made me guess that might  simplify things a bit! Thank you again!

Answer (score 6):

Hints:

1. If one varies infinitesimally the functional
   $$J[y]~:=~y(1)^2 + \int_0^1\! dx~ y^{\prime}(x)^2\tag{1}$$
   *without* discarding boundary contributions, one finds
   $$\begin{align} \delta J[y]~=~~~~~& 2 y(1)~\delta y(1) + 2\int_0^1\! dx~ y^{\prime}(x) ~\delta y^{\prime}(x)\cr
   \stackrel{\text{int. by parts}}{=}& 2\left[ y(1) + y^{\prime}(1)\right] \delta y(1)  -2 y^{\prime}(0)~\underbrace{\delta y(0)}_{=0} - 2\int_0^1\! dx~ y^{\prime\prime}(x) ~\delta y(x).\end{align} \tag{2}$$
2. Besides the given boundary condition $y(0)=1$, one concludes from formula (2) that a stationary configuration must obey
   $$ y(1) + y^{\prime}(1)~=~0\qquad\text{and} \qquad\forall x\in [0,1]:y^{\prime\prime}(x)~=~0.\tag{3}$$

Comment: Is there any reference or textbook that talks about functionals with an extra constant term (in this case boundary point) that also needs to be varied, particularly geared towards physics majors (not so concerned much about the formalism but more of the calculation)? At the very least I can study more about your calculation. Some books I’ve seen only briefly mentions about variation with free boundary point.

Comment: Hi mathemania. Thanks for the feedback. I'm sure boundary conditions are treated in many textbooks. However, I haven't checked which ones.

Comment: I've never seen this kind of problem in books in which there is an added constant term to the functional $J[y]$ that is outside the integral. Can you specifically mention what type this problem is or at least possibly point me to some material I can look into? Or even just keywords.

Answer (score 5):

Your approach is correct, but it could be expressed more precisely. The first step is to replace the free boundary problem by a more familiar variational problem: find
$$
M(c) = \inf\left\{\int_0^1 (y'(x))^2\,dx :  y(0)=1, \ y(1)=c \right\}\tag{1}
$$
Having found $M(c)$, you can minimize $c^2+M(c)$ over all $c\in\mathbb{R}$ and thus obtain the minimum of functional $J$.

The Euler-Lagrange equation for $(1)$ is $y''=0$, which leads to the minimizer $y(x) = 1+(c-1)x$ and subsequently $M(c) = (c-1)^2$.

Then $c^2+M(c) = c^2+(c-1)^2 $ is minimized at $ c= 1/2$, which delivers $\min J = 1/2$, attained by $y(x) = 1-x/2$.